# Broken package manager due to incorrect Banshee package

Tags: apt, package-management, banshee

Sup, so, I'm not familiar with linux at all so help is much appreciated. 
I've been trying to boot my pc up from a live CD unsuccessfully. I get to the stage at which there are the options to test without installing or install or so on where I select 'Install Ubuntu.' Here it relays through some fast DOS commands until it reaches 'end trace' and then, eventually, 'Killed.'

I have already got a functional 11.10 version installed, could this be a problem? The reason I am attempting a reinstall is because the package system is damaged inside 11.10, a problem I can't seem to solve. If I try to install any new software from within the software centre it tells me that two banshee extensions must be removed. I try to remove these from inside the terminal, using apt-get remove, which results in:**

You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore : Depends: banshee (>= 2.2.1) but 2.2.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The software centre suggests that I disable all third party repositories and run `apt-get install -f` I have done so but the package system remains damaged and `apt-get install -f`attempts to install banshee 2.2.1 but returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  banshee  
Suggested packages:  
  banshee-dbg  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
  banshee  
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.  
2 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/2,082 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 20.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
(Reading database ... 158653 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to replace banshee 2.2.0-1ubuntu2 (using .../banshee_2.2.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb)  ...  
Unpacking replacement banshee ...  
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/banshee_2.2.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb   (--unpack):  
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive  
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)  
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...  
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...  
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...  
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...  
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...  
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...  
Processing triggers for man-db ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/banshee_2.2.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried `apt-get update` (runs fine) and `apt-get upgrade`. The upgrade command 
`apt-get upgrade` results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 banshee-extension-soundmenu : Depends: banshee (>= 2.2.1) but 2.2.0-1ubuntu2 is installed
 banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore : Depends: banshee (>= 2.2.1) but 2.2.0-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I seem to be going round and round in circles here! If only I could reinstall successfully.

Only proposed updates (oneiric proposed) is not enabled.

Comment: Can you add a bit more of the log before the "errors were encountered while processing" line? It looks like the package it's downloading is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove banshee and any package that is related to it with `sudo apt-get purge banshee-*`

Comment: do a `sudo apt-get clean` which clears the archives, and then you can reinstall banshee. Please accept the answer.